# Dell XPS M1530 overheating

Tags: fan, cooling, dell-xps

My Dell XPS M1530 gets insanely hot. What can I do?

-- edit

I just confirmed that the cooling fan is not moving. Is there any way of replacing a laptop fan?

Comment: Define "insanely hot". How hot and where?

Comment: It gets so hot that it automatically shuts down. I cannot determine where.

Answer (score 2):

I would contact [Dell.](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dellcare/contact_us?c=us&l=en&s=gen&redirect=1) Maybe try [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/hwmonitor.php)

Answer (score 1):

If it's still under warranty I would try to see if you can send it into Dell to fix it. It could be a bad fan. Also, if everything is "technically good" then you can try using one of those Cool-Matts that is like a platform your laptop sets on with a lot of fans and such.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you call insanely hot, my cheap ASUS reaches 75degree in the summer when I play a game and the cpu is used intensily. 
You should get a software that can show you current temp and judge after that.

Comment: 75 degrees **Celsius**? Thats pretty hot! (in fact, thats the heat limit of a lot of CPUs)

Comment: I just confirmed that the fan is not moving. Is there any way of replacing a laptop fan?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=item&id=5206&sstate=GA&zipcode=30474&sstate=GA&zipcode=30474
that's the part you need to replace the fan / heat sink

And it's extremely easy to replace it.

Comment: you can edit your own answers to refine it, rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are lots of reports of Dell M1530 overheating.  You may want to google them.  There was a big issue awhile ago about this with Dell claiming it was a BIOS issue.  Here's a link, but there are many others.

http://www.techsupportforum.com/hardware-support/laptop-support/341302-dell-xps-m1530-overheating-redux.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with a simple clean of the fan and re-applying new thermal grease to the CPU and GPU. It's not as hard as it sounds. Take the heatsink and fan mechanism off following instructions [here](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/clean-replace-cooling-fan-dell-xps-m1530-laptop/), blow all the dust out of the fan, clean the old thermal grease off CPU and GPU and spread a thin layer of new onto both. Then put everything back together. The difference is amazing. My computer is running around 20-30 degrees cooler now. I'd also recommend [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) for keeping track of temperatures and monitoring fan speed.